# Getting 'IEnumerable`1 parameters' error in RDLC file

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am facing some wierd issue with my RDLC file.

I have created some RDLC file for them which is throwing `Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1 parameters)` error while calling.

I was using some parameters in a table and that table is associated to one dataset. When I remove the parameter from the table it's running fine.

Can't we use any parameters in a table in RDLC? The problem is if I am not putting this parameter inside the table it's very difficult to handle report layouts.

This is the code has been used to call the report.

```html
LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport();
List<ReportParameter> reportParams = new List<ReportParameter>();
localReport.ReportPath = Path.Combine(reportPath, reportRequest.ReportName);
...
 PMClientReportRequestDTO pmJUS = reportRequest as PMClientReportRequestDTO;
 ...
 reportParams.Add(new ReportParameter("jusStoreAddress", storeAddress));
 reportParams.Add(new ReportParameter("Culture", pmJUS.Culture));

 localReport.ReportPath = Path.Combine(reportPath, pmJUS.ReportName + ".rdlc");

 localReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("PurchasedMetalItems", pmJUS.PurchaseItems));
       ....
localReport.SetParameters(reportParams);
```

Comment: Do you have the code they are using in the .NET code?  I've embedded SSRS reports in both Winforms and WPF successfully, but I'd need to see what they are calling.  It sounds like they are passing an IEnumerable to the SetParameters function in a weird way.

Comment: Hi Sonny, I have got above code from the app dev team. Let me know if this is helpful to findout the problem.

Comment: Well, it looks like they are calling everything correctly.  `storeAddress` needs to be a string that is allowed by your parameters.  Are the parameters in your reports limited by available values?  Also, are your parameters named `jusStoreAddress` and `Culture`?  The only other thing I'm worried about is `pmJUS.Culture`.  This would need to be a string that is allowed by your parameter as well.

Comment: To summarize: there are a lot of moving parts between SSRS and .NET integration.  Make sure that the data they are feeding to your report matches the data your report is looking for.

Comment: Thanks Sonny, for all your feedback. I will check with the app dev team and will take a deep dive on this.